# Value relations QGIS

Tags: qgis, domains

I am trying to convert an ArcGIS based GIS setup to Open Source - QGIS.

In my old setup I had a lot of domains on an ArcSDE Database. I am struggling a bit to find a similar functionality in QGIS.

I have tried **Value Maps**, but they seem to be project file specific so whenever I am opening my project file on a new PC I have to define them again. This is not working for me as I am setting up a solution where more than one person needs to access the same data and work on it.

Another possible solution is **Value Relations**. I have succesfully created a table with my "domain values" and joined these to the layers in QGIS, but one big problem is that when I try to label my features they only show the key coloumn eg. a number. Instead I want to see what has been written in the value coloumn.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or perhaps know a better equivalent to domains in QGIS?

Comment: What kind of database are you using now?

Comment: For the value map part I tried to use SQLLite. For value Relations I would prefer to use either PostgreSQL or MSSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either using Value Maps or Value Relations, you will face the problem those setting being saved to the project only. One way of overcame that is to save the layer style as default.

[image]

Next time you, or anybody else, open that layer, the value maps will be there.

If you use a postgreSQL/PostGIS database, you can save the defaults there.

Comment: Tried this in 3.2, using a postgres table for my value relation. If I remove the table and add it again, the layer will loose the value relation setup despite having saved it as default.